# JavaScript function call in href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am attempting to call a basic javascript function through the href attribute in an `<a>` tag. I have done this countless times before, but now every browser is throwing exceptions in jQuery on the href javascript call and and some browsers elect not to run it but rather open a blank new window. I am just purplexed at this point. Any ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:showQuote(12);" data-toggle='modal' target='#quoteBox'>
        View Quote
    </a>
</td>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
function showQuote(id){
    $("#spot").load("viewQuote.php?id=" + id);
    $('#modal').modal('show');
}
```

Chrome is the only browser in which this works (it still throws an error). I have run this through some online validators and they turned up clean.

Also, I am using jQuery version 1.11.3.

Comment: It is very terrible practice to do this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/263690/38355

Comment: Why not just add an `onclick` event that fires the function instead of making it the href value?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but most browsers these days block `javascript:` URLs to protect against XSS attacks.

Comment: If you use _onclick_ as Nick Z suggests, _attach_ it via JS [`element.addEventLister(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or jQuery `$('something').click(...)` ***not*** by putting an _onclick=_ within the `<a>` tag. And I second _["Why is the use of JavaScript in HREF attributes discouraged?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/263686/3767)_ on Programmers.SE

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @gladsocc I doubt that. There's no difference in vulnerability between `href="javascript:blah"` and `onclick="blah"`

Comment: Hey everyone. Thanks for the replies. The reason I am not using a generic event listener is because there is an instance of this line for each entry and their are hundreds of entries (the parameter is the ID number that varies per entry).

Comment: @StephenCioffi Add `data-id="12"` to the element, and use `$(this).data("id")` in the generic event listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to write this in "jquery" style.

**Updated answer - using current controls id**

```
<td>
    <a href="" data-toggle='modal' id="12" class="mylink" target='#quoteBox'>
        View Quote
    </a>
</td>
```

In Document.Ready..

```
 $('.mylink').on('click',function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#spot").load("viewQuote.php?id=" + id);
      $('#modal').modal('show');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
 <td><a href="javascript:showQuote(12,event);" data-toggle='modal' target='#quoteBox'>View Quote</a></td>
```

> Javascript

```
function showQuote(id,event){
$("#spot").load("viewQuote.php?id=" + id);
$('#modal').modal('show');
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;
}
```